# What does the Extreme Hills biome do on a Superflat world?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Just got the 1.8 update on Xbox One, and I'm experimenting with the superflat editing options.

If you start to create a new Superflat world, go to advanced Superflat options, and then the Biomes tab, there's a Biome called Extreme Hills. If I create a world with this biome, even using the preset "Tunnelers Dream" which has this biome, there are no hills.

What is the effect of the Extreme Hills biome, if it can be applied to a Superflat?

Comment: Since the two are opposites of each other, I would say that one cancels out the other. And from what you have described, that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Then why would that be an option?

Comment: And why would they make a preset that uses it?

Comment: its usually a case of standardised menu applying to everything. Does not always mean it will make sense. If that is the case, asking "why would they do that" leads to speculation on the game developers thoughts when making the game. That said, if it is an option that has **no effect in this particular case**, why wouldn't they leave it in? it has no negative impact on the game, and it saves them having to set up a new interface.

Comment: But that interface is *only* available for superflat worlds. And that option is used by Mojang or 4J in a preset for world creating. Not sure it's meaningless if they used it in a demo. I just don't think it does what I'd expect. I just can't see what it does at all, at the moment.

Comment: It would also affect the spawning of ores; Extreme Hills biomes will have Emerald Ore spawn when `decoration` is set; other biomes wont.

Comment: @Batophobia This question was asked prior to the release of bedrock edition. The meta post you linked to only described how Minecraft versions are currently organized, not how they were organized in 2015.

Comment: @pppery The current stance is that Xbox One version of Minecraft should use the bedrock tag, since that's what users finding this question will be using.  I could be wrong, though, so feel free to start a meta discussion if you disagree.

Comment: @Batophobia It is a fact that the current version of Minecraft for Xbox One is Bedrock Edition. The stance you linked to says that questions about Bedrock Edition on any platform be tagged [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition], not that questions about any version of Minecraft for which Bedrock Edition was later released be given that tag, even though an entirely different edition was being played by the asker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it means "biome" it really means what color the grass is, leaves, etc. The actual terrain does not get affected, because it is superflat. So extreme hills biome in superflat is basically NOT desert looking grass/leaves/dirt or not swamp looking. An example: [image]

See the different colors? That is the difference.

Comment: snow can also fall at high y-coordinates in extreme hills

Answer (score 0):

Extreme hills biome may cause spruce trees to spawn in a Superflat world.

Comment: Do you think you could go into a little more detail? Generally, one - sentence answers are discouraged, on Arqade. Maybe add information on how Spruce Trees can be more efficiently grown within the environment, what bonuses they give, maybe a picture?